# What is ip table

Tags: ip, iptables

I am doing a php site. Each time i restart the server i need  to disable ip tables..  What is the use of ip tables.. Someone please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPTables is a Linux firewall tool. It controls which packets are allowing into and out of your system. I'd recommend that you read up on how to configure IPTables and set it up so that your server is allowed access instead of disabling it - you're opening up a big security hole by disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

iptables is a firewall.  Not sure why you're disabling iptables for a php site.